# Print ALL defined variables/method signatures in Spark Shell - Scala REPL

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

When I use the `spark-shell` I end up defining many `var`, `val`, and `methods`. At some point I forget what I have available in my session. How do I print that?

e.g.

```
val x = 10;
var y = 15;
def myMethod(input: Int): Int = { input * 2 }

// invoke magic print command to obtain something like:
// > val x;
// > var y;
// > myMethod(input: Int): Int;
```

**EDIT (Clarification):**

If I type the following:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int, y: Int): Int = { x * y }
foo: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
scala> def bar(x: Int, y: Int): Int = { x / y }
bar: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
```

Is there anything that I could type to print only the following for the method defined by me?

```
foo: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
bar: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something similar to this:

```
$intp.definedTerms
  .map(t => s"${t.toTermName}: ${$intp.typeOfTerm(t.toTermName.toString)}")
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: This gives all the spark variables too not just what I defined. I tried a variety of commands other than the one above nothing works.
 $intp.definedSymbolList,
 $intp.namedDefinedTerms, $intp.definedTerms.filter(x => !x.startsWith("res")).foreach(println), $intp.allDefinedNames.filter(!_.startsWith("$")) everything returns back spark variables